# Return type XmlDocument of an Asp.Net webservice changes to XmlNode when accessing the webmethod

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a Web Method in Web service which is returning an XmlDocument. The Web service works fine when i am executing it  and providing the necessary parameters.

I have created a proxy to this service in another application.proxy is created well and good.

Now the problem is,when i try to access the methods from that service its getting all the methods from the service but the return type of the method is showing as XmlNode instead of XmlDocument.

Let us say for example:

### Service.asmx

```
public class DataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument GetData(int ID)
    {
            //Code Here
    }
}
```

Now i have one windows application which is using this service.

Created an object to the service through proxy.

```
DRService.DataService  drService = new DRService.DataService();
```

Now i am trying to access the service methods.

```
drService.GetData(1)
```

The return type of the above method call should be XmlDocument but it is returning XmlNode as return type.

Any idea why the retun type is XmlNode?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.